# Is it ok to use a QUdpSocket in different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want to a QUdpSocket but read/write data in different threads like this:

```
void UDPLink::writeBytes(const char* data, qint64 size)
{
    // Broadcast to all connected systems
    for (int h = 0; h < hosts.size(); h++)
    {
        QHostAddress currentHost = hosts.at(h);
        quint16 currentPort = ports.at(h);
        socket->writeDatagram(data, size, currentHost, currentPort);
    }
}

void UDPLink::readBytes()
{
    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());

        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &sender, &senderPort);

        // FIXME TODO Check if this method is better than retrieving the data by individual processes
        emit bytesReceived(this, datagram);
     }
}
```

The `readBytes()` is triggered the socket's `readyRead` signal.
However the writeBytes is in a worker thread, and the readBytes is in the main thread. Is this Ok?

Comment: `QUdpSocket` is reentrant class. You may read Qt documentation for details - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However the writeBytes is in a worker thread, and the readBytes is in
>   the main thread. Is this Ok?

If you were using a raw POSIX socket (e.g. an int file descriptor and the BSD socket API's sendto() call) it would be okay; however QUdpSocket derives from QObject, and QObjects are not intended to be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.  In particular, a quick look at the QUdpSocket::writeDatagram() method implementation shows that method doing things like lazy-initialization of the underlying socket, caching of the file descriptor, and emitting of a signal, any of which could interact poorly with simultaneous unsynchronized access from a different thread given the right (wrong?) timing.  Your code might get away with doing it, but I wouldn't trust it to work reliably all the time or on all systems.

My suggestion would be instead to create two QUdpSocket objects, one for sending and one for receiving.  That will ensure that race conditions are avoided, and an extra QUdpSocket object is not a very large cost to pay for peace of mind.

Comment: Can I bind two udpsocket to the same port? Is there any example on this?

Comment: You don't need to -- only the socket that is receiving incoming UDP packets needs to be bound to the well-known port number, since the other socket won't be receiving packets anyway.  For the socket that is sending the UDP packets, you can just bind it to port 0, which will cause the OS to choose a currently-available port to bind it to.